# how can I make a ball move by hit with a stick?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my homework: Python, using tkinter/Spyder.
In Python, I want to make a simulation : There is a fixed ball in a canvas, and use a stick to hit the ball(collision) and make it move.

I can make the stick move, but cannot hit the ball and the ball doesn't move at all. The stick just goes through the ball. Or, if I make the ball move by giving the velocity, then the ball moves by itself without hitting.

```
def get_position(self):
    return self.canvas.coords(self.item)

# ...

def check_collisions(self):
    Ball_coords = self.Ball.get_position()
    items = [Stick, Ball]
    items = self.canvas.find_overlapping(Ball_coords)
    items = [self.items[x] for x in items if x in self.items]
    self.Ball.collide(items)  

def move(self, velocity):
    coords = self.get_position()
    width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
    if coords[0] + velocity >= 0 and coords[2] + velocity <= width: 
#coords == [x1, y1, x2, y2]
        super(Stick, self).move(velocity, 0)
vx = -3
vy = 0
dt = .1
for it in range(100000):   
    dx = vx * dt
    dy = vy * dt
    x += dx
    if x-r < xmin : vx = -vx
    if y-r < ymin : vy = -vy
    if x+r > xmax : vx = -vx
    if y+r > ymax : vy = -vy

canvas.move(Ball,dx,dy)
window.update()
time.sleep(0.000001)
```

I expect the collision with a ball and a stick makes move the ball, but, the actual output is the ball doesn't move at all or just move itself without collision.